# Typescript: c.setValue is not a function

Tags: angular

I'm trying to trim leading and trailing whitespace.

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt1" formControlName="txt1" (blur)="MyTrim($event.target)">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt2" formControlName="txt2" (blur)="MyTrim($event.target)">
</form>
```

ts

```
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
...
MyTrim(c: FormControl)
{
    c.setValue("XY"); // err from here
}
```

Comment: Bcz `c` is not a `FormControl` its a plain text string and you can not setValue to string

Comment: it is not a string, it is a html input element in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$event.target is not a formControl
you can try this:

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt1" formControlName="txt1" (blur)="MyTrim("txt1")">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt2" formControlName="txt2" (blur)="MyTrim("txt2")">
</form>
```

ts:

```
MyTrim(key: string)
{
    this.myForm.get(key).setValue("XY");
}
```

or

```
{
        this.myForm.controls[key].setValue("XY");   
 }
```